# Error: Cannot find module 'react-router/lib/getRouteParams'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, solidity, truffle

I did npm -install -react-router-dom and all the good nonense, I have react-router in the node modules. I cannot seem to find the solution to this problem.

Below is the Error Code.

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\EthSwap.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Token.sol     
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\ssand\AppData\Local\Temp\test--2500-cjuPSMOV4zat
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

Error: Cannot find module 'react-router/lib/getRouteParams'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\node_modules\react-bootstrap\lib\Breadcrumb.js
- C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\test\EthSwap.test.js
- C:\Users\ssand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js
- C:\Users\ssand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\index.js
- C:\Users\ssand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\node_modules\react-bootstrap\lib\Breadcrumb.js:28:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\test\EthSwap.test.js:8:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at loader (C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at C:\Users\ssand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:390:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
Truffle v5.4.19 (core: 5.4.19)
Node v14.17.5
PS C:\Users\ssand\eth_swap>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install react-router-dom --save
```

If it did not work, try to verify your path env variable and add the directory that you installed react module.